# Install Win7 from recovery - protect current lubuntu install

Tags: windows-7, lubuntu

I got a new laptop in December and immediately wiped Windows, installed Ubuntu (later tried XFCE, KDE, now LXDE and happy), and left the recovery partition intact. The idea was that if anything was wrong with the laptop, I could restore Win7 from the recovery for warantee purposes...

I'm having some major sound issues, and finally getting around to looking into it. I'd like to reinstall Win 7 to ensure the sound issues are not hardware (speakers), before pursuing lengthy troubleshooting (I've done the basic stuff already).

1. Can I do this?
2. Can I do this AND preserve my current Lubuntu install, with some degree of confidence? I understand there is always a risk when repartitioning.
3. How?
   Thanks!

Comment: Answer is yes you can do it

first Reinstall win7 normally 
then update grub boot loader using livecd

similar question is answered somewhere in this website

Answer (score 2):

If you have only two partition (RECOVERY partition and Ubuntu Partition with rest of the hard drive), you need to create a new partition and restore windows 7 on newly created partition. To create a partition you can use default partition manager tool in ubuntu OR any disk utilities like acronics disk director,EASUS PARTITION MANAGER (free).

> These third party tools need to be installed in a windows system, and
>   then you can create a boot able cd/usb for booting and managing.

1. First re-size the current ubuntu partition and use free space to
   create a new partition (ref link: - [How to create new partitions in a brand new laptop easily and safely](http://webe.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-create-new-partitions-in-a-brand-new-laptop-easily-and-safely))
2. After that you can use the tool called boot-repair to update the
   grub. (ref Link- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

---

If you have installed ubuntu on a separate partition and you have a free partition (I mean no important data, as it will deleted while installing win 7), then install win 7 on that partition. Then use live cd/usb to update the grub using the tool mentioned above.

> Note: I hope you got a restoration dvd created if you want factory
>   image restore. If you want to use your factory image stored in
>   RECOVERY partition. You need to extract the image file (with extension
>   .vim) and "imagex" tool for re-deployment. Its a bit advanced task.

Comment: I think this answers my question. Can you explain more about your Note?

Comment: **Take back up before doing anything**

First you need access to the RECOVERY partition. First mount the device using 
`sudo mkdir /storage ` then 
`sudo mount /dev/sda* /storage` 

where * denotes the partition number of recovery partition. You can use gparted for determining that.

Now copy all wim files to another location (may be usb stick). Now if you have more than one image files first those things needs to be merged. (see here - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/mdt/thread/137bcb32-8546-4237-a2e1-51fecd8c365d)

Comment: After that you can create a new partition for windows 7, assign it as drive C: and apply the image as told here -> http://mildlyhacked.blogspot.in/2010/05/using-imagex-to-restore-wim-image-from.html

You need to copy imagex and merged wim image (if any) to usb disk / or hard disk (that is accessible in cmd ) and use it. Just read through above article you will understand.

You can download only imagex tool from here
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26252340/imagex.zip